# Interface errors

Tags: 16.04, networking, server

Since 2 days don't internet for my test server and today I found out something interesting which is the following:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         213.156.10.17   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.201.2      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 Albert
192.9.200.0     10.0.201.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 Albert
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
213.156.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
213.156.10.16   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth0
```

So that gateway of eth0 on the top of the list should be with the one on the bottom and when I check my `/etc/network/interfaces` they are together and when I restart the service nothing changes

The interface file:

> The primary network interface
>
> auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static
>
> ```
>     address 213.156.10.20
>     gateway 213.156.10.17
>     netmask 255.255.255.240
> ```

There are a few other lines but they are # case they were old but sometimes needed to try something out

Also the second eth0 from the bottom shouldn't be there at all so what is going on? cause this wasn't like that two days ago or yesterday when I checked

edit1: Mikael Schultz requested that i do a few commands so here they are
ip address

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:21:f2:75:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 213.156.10.20/28 brd 213.156.10.31 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::213:21ff:fef2:753d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:21:f2:75:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.164/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::213:21ff:fef2:753c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:0a:61:9b:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:0a:61:9b:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.253/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global eth3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
7: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: Albert@eth0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1476 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/gre 213.156.10.20 peer 212.57.52.228
    inet 10.0.201.1 peer 10.0.201.2/32 brd 10.0.201.255 scope global Albert
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::200:5efe:d59c:a14/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ping 213.156.10.17

```
PING 213.156.10.17 (213.156.10.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 213.156.10.20 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 213.156.10.20 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 213.156.10.20 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 213.156.10.20 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 213.156.10.20 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 213.156.10.20 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 213.156.10.17 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6017ms
pipe 3
```

ping 8.8.8.8

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: Could you edit your post with the output of the command `ip address`? Also with `ping 213.156.10.17` and `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after having some help from a college at work the problem was quickly solved with a few tweaks in `/ect/network/interfaces` and in the firewall so everything is back in working order still thanks for the effort Mikael Schultz